# Start a shell process in Gulp with callback when process started

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to run some tasks in Gulp, sequentially. One of those tasks is a shell script that performs a simple `$ node app.js`. How can I fire the callback so I can tell Gulp that the server has started?

**tl;dr**

---

So here's the bigger picture of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm using gulp [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence) to fire up a number of tasks sequentially, which specifies a couple ways you should be writing your tasks in order for them to be run in sequence.

Each `gulp.task()` must either:

- `return` the `stream`
  or
- call a callback on the task

### My setup:

- `gulp.task("clean", ..); // returns the stream, all OK`
- `gulp.task("compile", ..); // returns the stream, all OK`
- `gulp.task("spin-server", ..); // calls the callback with a hack`
- `gulp.task("init-browser-sync", ..); // last task`

Here's my `spin-server` task:

```
gulp.task("spin-server", function(cb) {
  exec("sh shell-utilities/spin-server");

  // @HACK allow time for the server to start before `runSequence`
  // runs the next task.
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb();
  }, 2500);
});
```

And here's the `spin-server.sh` shell script:

```
## Start Node server ##

node server/app.js

#######
# EOF #
#######
```

### The problem

Right now I'm using a `setTimeout` hack to make sure my Node/Express server has fired up before proceeding to run the `init-browser-sync` task.

How can I eliminate that `setTimeout` hack and call `cb()` when my Express server actually fires up?

Comment: Where is `exec` coming from?

Comment: `child_process` is assume. correct?

Comment: @PatrickGoley  `require("child_process").exec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to spawn a process but listen to it's output, you can start it with `exec` and then attach listeners to the stdout of the process.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task("spin-server", function() {

  var child = exec("sh shell-utilities/spin-server");

  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });
  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });
  child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
  });
});
```

Comment: So right now I do this: `if(data.toLowerCase().includes("listening")) { return cb(); }` and I'm wondering if there's any way of not coupling my gulpfile with what the server outputs after it fires up - isn't there like a general hint I could probably use? In any case, thanks - I've went with your example.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides the best solution I can think of is to make the keyword an argument into the spin-server script. Instead of hardcoding 'listening' it prints out whatever keyword is passed in from the gulp file.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of `exec` (`require('child_process').spawn`) like this :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task("spin-server", function(cb) {
  var srv = spawn("sh shell-utilities/spin-server");

  srv.stdout.on('data', data => {
    if(data.includes('server listening')) { // Or whatever your server outputs when it's done initializing
      console.log('Server initialization completed');
      return cb();
    }
  });
});
```

When the string `server listening` is found in the output of the spawned process, the `cb()` is called and the server is guaranteed to be initialized at that point.

Answer (score 2):

```
gulp.task("spin-server", function(cb) {
  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const process = spawn('bash', ['', 'setup.sh']);

  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      if(data = "SCRIPT CHECKPOINT")
          cb();
      });
});
```

Use `spawn` for non blocking async exec.

Let your `setup.sh` file print `"SCRIPT CHECKPOINT"` or something similar to inform that the server is up and running".

This will trigger the `cb()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the callback would get called after the process has `exited` in this scenario.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides we can then monitor for a particular stdout and then call the callback?

Comment: you mean I should just change `require("child_process").exec` to `require("child_process").spawn` ?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides like this. Will be async too, if you want to do other not dependant code execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 
gulp.task('spin-server', function (cb) {
  exec('sh shell-utilities/spin-server', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);

    if (err || stdout.indexOf('runSequence') > -1) {
      cb(err);
    }
  });
})
```