# Start node server via shell and print something when done

Tags: node.js, shell, gulp

I'm looking for a way to start a Node server via a shell command and print something afterwards.

**tl;dr**

I have a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task that:

- Starts a node server by issuing a `$ node server/app.js` command
- Must call a callback `cb()` *after* the server has started up.

Now, for the callback to fire properly there are 2 solutions I can use:

#### Solution 1

- **Have the server output something after startup**

Example `server/app.js`:

```
http.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000), function(){
  console.log("start");
});
```

This solution is **not ideal**.

- It introduces coupling between the gulpfile.js and server/app.js.
- The coupling is that 'start' keyword.

#### Solution 2

- **Issue an `$ echo` command when issuing a `$ node server/app.js` command**

Example:

```
$ node server.app.js && echo 'start'
```

This is the **ideal** since it doesn't couple what my `app.js` file is printing with my `gulpfile.js`.

The above doesn't work - when running it, it just outputs what my server has configured to be printing on startup. The `'start'` string never get's printed.

#### The gulptask

```
gulp.task("node server/app.js && echo 'start'", function(cb) {

  serverProcess.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    if(data.toLowerCase().includes("start")) {
      return cb();
    }
  });
});
```

The above task of course won't work but it's a good ballpark of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You problem is `node server/app.js` does not background itself, it runs in the foreground and blocks so the `&& echo 'start'` which is waiting for node to finish never actually gets run. I get the feeling you are trying to solve the wrong problem and the best way to work around this depends on what you are trying to achieve overall. Is this a dev task? for production? what are your trying to do after your application starts? why does your application not do this task?

Comment: @MichaelDaffin The bigger picture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190673/start-a-shell-process-in-gulp-with-callback-when-process-started

Comment: If it's an express app, why not use the gulp-express plugin to do so? Then you get the luxury of gulp integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a real solution for this, because the node application is blocking, you will never now when it started without using some clues from the application itself. The one thing that you could do that would work without outputting a string from the server, is checking if the node application is listening on its port. Something like `netstat -ant | awk '$6 == "LISTEN" && $4 ~ /\.4000$/'` where the 4000 is the port on which the node-app is listening.

But I would recommend that you keep your first approach, the coupling isn't such a big deal in my opinion.

Comment: No but I live and breathe for the coupling paranoia - all kidding aside these are problems that I constantly run into - someone changes what `app.js` outputs after startup, things don't load in-time or don't start at all and we spend half a day debugging this - I'll take the paranoia over this 1000 times. Have you seen @Samuel Rossile's answer below? What's wrong with `sleep`?

Comment: `sleep` is also a coupling on the startup-time of the application (which can greatly vary). I would suggest just adding a comment to the node-application itself with `do not change, this output is needed for another application`. But if the startup time is not varying that much and the startup time isn't that long, `sleep` is perfectly fine.

Comment: doesn't `sleep` run *after* the server has started? Or do they run "concurrently"? If the latter's the case then it's not only coupling it, it becomes a race condition no?

Comment: They run at the same time, correct. It's certainly something that can fail anytime, but most of the time it won't, because you often add some seconds on top of the normal startup time. So `node server/app.js & sleep 100 && echo 'start'` will probably always succeed, but `node server/app.js & sleep 1 && echo 'start'` not so much, then it's a race condition as you said.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep my current approach in that case

Comment: Glad I could help, btw: you'll never find a perfect solution for this, this is a variation of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `$ node server/app.js && echo 'start'` is that whatever is after `&&` will only run after the server process has finished running, not after it has started.

What you want is to run something after the server has started.

You can achieve this with something like that `$ node server/app.js & sleep 2 && echo 'start'` (sleep because you want to give it some time to actually connect to actually start before saying it has started)

Note: I think it's quite conventional to say that the server is listening on port XXXX in the log of a server.

Comment: *Race condition* :) - What if the server takes 3s to fire-up?